# cant dispaly the content of array in flatlist when its length = 1

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using flat list to display the content of an array. When the array.length = 1 it doesn't display the content, but if its length > 1 it display the content as expected.

here is my code:

```
return (
    <FlatList data={this.state.services}
        renderItem={({item})=> {
            var query = "select * from service_details where service_id = " + item;
            var all_national_numbers = [];
            db.transaction((tx) =>{
                tx.executeSql(query,[],(tx,results) =>{
                    for(let i = 0 ; i < results.rows.length ; i++){
                        let row = results.rows.item(i);
                        all_national_numbers[i] = row.national_number;
                    }                    
                   var len = all_national_numbers.length ;
                   console.log(len)
                 });
            });
            return(
                <FlatList 
                    data={all_national_numbers}
                    renderItem={({item}) => {
                       if(all_national_numbers.length ==1){
                            return(
                                <View>
                                    <Text>{item}</Text>
                                </View>
                            )
                        } else{
                            return(
                                <View>
                                    <Text>{item}</Text>
                                </View>
                            )
                        }
                    }}
                />
            )
        }}
    />
)
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: But: I think *you* should further improve the formatting of your code. You want others to spend their time to help you, so *you* please make our input as easy to read as possible.

Comment: Your if and else statement inside the second `FlatList` is literally rendering the same thing.. Try changing `{item}` to `Test1` and `Test2` to see if it's actually giving you that bug

Comment: Above comment, Or remove the conditional rendering at all. Plus you should use '===' for better checking